# Display shadow on a photo

Tags: html, css, dropshadow

I was trying to do something similar to this photo (concerning the shadow **on** the picture at the bottom). [Photo with Shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hBIJf.png)

This is what have got so far:

```html
<style>
    h2.header {
    bottom: 0;
    position: absolute;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    }
    .wrapper {
        display: inline-block;
        margin-top: 25px;
        position: relative;  
    }

    .wrapper img {
    display: block;
    max-width:100%;
    }

    .wrapper .overlay {
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.25);
    color:white;
    }
    </style>

    <div class="wrapper">
    <img src="http://www.kavoir.com/img/text-over-image.jpg"  alt="" />
    <div class="overlay">
    <h2 class="header">Restaurant Stowaway Devours $800 of Roast Goose and Wine</h2>

     </div>
     </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can let a div with a image as background, then let a gradient object inside of it.

```css
body {
  width: 100%
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0px;
  overflow: hidden;
}

#image {
  width: 660px;
  height: 200px;
  position: relative;
  background: url('http://i.imgur.com/HNj6tRD.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: 100% 100%;
}

#grad {
  width: 660px;
  height: 200px;
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,1)); /* For Safari 5.1 to 6.0 */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,1)); /* For Opera 11.1 to 12.0 */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,1)); /* For Firefox 3.6 to 15 */
    background: linear-gradient(rgba(0,0,0,0), rgba(0,0,0,1)); /* Standard syntax (must be last) */
}
```

```html
<div id="image" alt=image><div id=grad></div></div>
```

Comment: it was a bit scary the messages of your edits while I was changing the code. Anyway, that's fine now;

Comment: Really? It still looks stretched! Why did you keep rejecting my edits?

Comment: I only refused 1 edit; all others were rejected by the community. My objective with this image was to fit 100% the little snippet. [**This is how I see it on my screen**](http://i.imgur.com/62JnM5N.png)

Comment: Sorry for accusing you of blocking my edits! That's how I see the image too too! Anyway, good answer!

Comment: Edits like yours are only allowed on **community wiki posts**; otherwise, you only can change things that breaks up the stackoverflow guidelines (example: unecessary text "hey dudes here is my dumb code").

Comment: [**these are free to edit/improve**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit-community-wiki)

Comment: Thanks! I don't quite have enough rep.